# Email temporary file with Outlook

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, wsh, jscript

I want to create a file, email it as an attachment, then delete the file, using JScript.

The problem lies in the fact that deleting the file too soon will prevent Outlook from attaching the file to the email.

I will be creating a MailItem and displaying it with something like the following code. The email will not automatically be sent, but it will be displayed so the user can edit it if necessary.

```
var outlook = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
var msg = outlook.CreateItem(0);
msg.Recipients.Add(toAddress);
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.htmlbody = body;
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
msg.Display();
```

My question is, **when is it safe to delete the attachment file?** I know MailItem has events, where I could maybe delete the attachment file in the AttachmentAdd event. But, AFAIK, there is no way to subscribe to ActiveXObject events in JScript.

My thoughts:

- I could delete the file immediately, if Attachments.Add is synchronous (or if Display waits until all attachments have been read)
- I could sleep for x seconds, and then delete the file.
- Maybe there is a way to subscribe to an event, and I haven't found it.

Details:

This script is, for all intents and purposes, running in wscript.

This is not specific to any Outlook version. It should work with any version.

I will also be attaching several other files to the email.

If you have questions, just ask.

Comment: Can you create it in the temp folder and mark it to be deleted on next reboot, etc?

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: I probably could, but the sooner the file is deleted, the better.

Comment: If you need to get rid of it fast due to security concerns Outlook is probably not a good choice. Outlook stores a copy of the file in the temp dir before sending and then in the users PST file after sending.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: It's not because of security. I'm not sure what all is involved, because of where I am getting the file, but it may avoid issues with filename collisions.

Comment: From everything I can tell outlook should copy the file into its temp OLK directory when you call Add. You can verify this by looking in your User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet files\OLK* directory after you call Add

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: But it is synchronous? i.e. Can I delete my file *immediately* after calling Add?

Comment: For a different thought, you can always avoid filename collisions by adding a timestamp to the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code and it worked.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

var outlook = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
var msg = outlook.CreateItem(0);
msg.Subject = "Subject";
msg.Body = "Body";
msg.Attachments.Add(file);
fso.DeleteFile(file); // No problems.
msg.Display();
```

It isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation, but `Attachments.Add()` seems to be synchronous.